# docker build is not creating an image

Tags: docker, sbt

I have an sbt project i have written a dockerFile in its root directory here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8

MAINTAINER name <email@gmail.com>


RUN echo "==> run the project..."       && \
    echo "==> it will take some time!!!"  && \
    sbt run


WORKDIR /hazelcastscalaserver


# Define default command.
CMD ["sbt", "run"]
```

when i do `docker build -t test/project .`
instead of dcoker creating an image it started to run the command here is expected behviour should be it shpuld build the image then i will run the image through `docker run test/project:latest` and my project started to run but its not happening where i am mistaken ?

here is the result of `docker build`

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  208.1MB
Step 1/5 : FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8
 ---> 349a7e4f4029
Step 2/5 : MAINTAINER name <name@gmail.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e92083819853
Step 3/5 : RUN echo "==> run the project..."       &&     echo "==> it will take some time!!!"  &&     sbt run
 ---> Running in 226ce249a353
==> run the project...
==> it will take some time!!!
[info] Updated file /root/project/build.properties: set sbt.version to 1.2.8
[info] Loading project definition from /root/project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/root/project/"), "root-build")...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/root/)
[info] Updating ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Packaging /root/target/scala-2.12/root_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed May 2, 2019, 12:37:43 PM
The command '/bin/sh -c echo "==> run the project..."       &&     echo "==> it will take some time!!!"  &&     sbt run' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Your `RUN` step fails with a exit code 1
At this point docker break up the build and don't generate a image.

Comment: It says `[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.` Is there a main class?

Comment: You probably need to `COPY` your code in before you `RUN` the build step.